# What is the relation between zebra font 0 font size parameters and actual text size in dots?

Tags: font-size, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl

I create a text in ZPL format using zebra font 0, which is a scalable font.  I need to calculate the text width and height, however I didn't know the relation between ZPL font parameter and letter size in dots. The ZPL command used to create text are :

`^FO15,19^A0,20,20^FDSample_text^FS`

The parameter 20,20 supposed to be font height (h) and width(w) in dots on the manual, however when I use font type 0 and test it, the height and width (20,20) not equal to the size of letter in dots.

What is the unit of height and width font parameter for scalable font? Is there a formula to calculate text height and width in dots for all font size input?

Comment: The resolution of your printer is important to consider as Zebra printers can be 203, 300 or 600 DPI (dot per inch).  Given the resolution of your printer, does the printed size better match what you are expecting?

Comment: My printer is 203 dpi (8dot/mm). What I'm confused about is when I input font height and width to 20, the height and width is not 20 dots. I check using online zpl viewer url: http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=15&height=10&units=mm&index=0&rotation=0&zpl=%0AZPL%20code%20test%0A%5EXA%0A%5EFO15%2C19%5EA0%2C20%2C20%5EFDSample_text%5EFS%0A%5EFO15%2C19%2C%5EGB20%2C20%0A%5EXZ
Compared to ZPL box, the length is not 20 dots. The scale value varies a lot when I try different font sizes. I still didn't find the relation between font input and actual letter size. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this article might be helpful. [How to calculate the font width, ZPL](https://developer.zebra.com/thread/35990)